# Why worry about minifying JS and CSS when images are typically the largest sized HTTP request?

Tags: image, httprequest, minify, image-resizing

I think my question says it all. With many successful sites using lots of user inputted images (e.g., Instagram), it just seems, in my perhaps naive opinion, that source code minification might be missing the boat.

Regardless of the devices one is coding for (mobile/desktop/both), wouldn't developers time be better spent worrying about the images they are serving up rather than their code sizes?

For optimizing for mobile browsers slower speeds, I was thinking it would probably be best to have multiple sized images and write code to serve up the smallest ones if the user is on a phone.

Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Generally, JS and CSS requests are blocking i.e. theoretically, further html is not "rendered" by the browser until a referred Javascript is downloaded and parsed. In case of images, the browser doesn't block and images can be downloaded in parallel on a separate thread while the html processing continues further. Thus, large images do not have as huge impact on the user experience as large javascript files referred in the head of the html.

Comment: hi Kiran, I'm loading my JS at the bottom of the page so it should be non-blocking. Also, I don't like that rendering effect of large images where they fill out from top to bottom in front of your eyes. It looks crappy and people start thinking cheap webpage. If you could serve up smaller images depending on the device then you'd be less likely to see this top-bottom ugly rendering, don't you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I don't know that many developers do "worry" about minification of scripts. Plenty of public facing websites don't bother.

Second, minification is the removal of unnecessary whitespace whereas decreasing the size of an image usually entails reducing it's quality so there is some difference.

Third, I believe that if it weren't so easy to implement a minification step into a deployment process it would be even less popular. It doesn't save much bandwidth true but if all it takes is a few minutes to configure a deployment script to do it then why not?

Comment: hi Spencer, thanks for your thoughts, I'm not advocating to not minify your scripts since it is so easy. As Brad says, why not? I guess I'm just wondering if developers actually serve up different sized images depending on the device.

Comment: Probably not. But I doubt that the client's bandwidth is the reason for improving the size of a webpage anymore. At least when we're talking about a difference of 10kb. The user isn't going to notice the difference. Server bandwidth is more expensive though and 10kb when you're serving upwards of several hundred thousand hits an hour adds up quick.

Comment: by "improving the size of a webpage" do you mean "faster loading of a webpage"? I'd think browser performance could have just as much of an impact on a business as server costs.

Comment: I apologize I clarified what I meant. I don't think that minification often has a substantial impact for the client. If a web master becomes concerned that their page takes to long to load I think they usually go looking for more substantial areas to save space. Eliminating content, pictures etc.

Answer (score 1):

100KB of data for a medium-sized JS library is no light-weight.  You should optimize your site as best as possible.  If by minifying a script you can get it to half of its size, and then by gzipping it, save another third, why wouldn't you?

I don't know how you do your minifying, but there are many scripts that automate the process, and will often bundle all of your JS into one package on the fly.  This saves bandwidth, and hassle.

My philosophy is always "use what you need".  If it is possible to save bandwidth for you and your users without compromising anything, then do it.  If you can compress your images way down and they still look good, then do it.  Likewise, if you have some feature that your web application absolutely must have, and it takes quite a bit of space, use it anyway.

Comment: hi Brad, thanks for your thoughts, I'm not advocating to not minify your scripts since it is so easy. I guess I'm just wondering if developers actually serve up different sized images depending on the device. It would appear that sites could typically have up to 100, many KB images or large movie/song files which could dwarf even a 100KB JS library in terms of file size.

Comment: thanks, i'm going to do this, whats your suggestion for best JS bundler? I'm still pretty much a novice so easy of use is still important for me.